# SQL Server stored procedure that requires varchar param not working as expected

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I'm fairly new to SQL, so please forgive any ignorant questions.

Here is my stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search_highlights]
    @page INT = 1,
    @recsPerPage INT = 20,
    @query NVARCHAR(MAX) = ''
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON

    DECLARE @FirstRec AS INT = (@page - 1) * @recsPerPage,
            @LastRec AS INT = (@page * @recsPerPage + 1)

    SELECT
        [id],
        [datetime],
        [player_ids], [player_names],
        [headline], [duration],
        [blurb], [bigblurb],
        [thumb_s], [thumb_m], [thumb_l],
        [video_s], [video_m], [video_l],
        [gameid],
        [team_id], [team_name]
    FROM 
        (SELECT
             [id],
             [datetime],
             [player_ids], [player_names],
             [headline],
             [duration],
             [blurb], [bigblurb],
             [thumb_s], [thumb_m], [thumb_l],
             [video_s], [video_m], [video_l],
             [gameid],
             [team_id], [team_name],
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY datetime DESC) AS rn
         FROM 
             [bbt].[dbo].[highlights]
         WHERE 
             CONTAINS((player_names, headline, blurb, bigblurb, team_name), @query)
        ) hp
    WHERE 
        rn BETWEEN @FirstRec AND @LastRec
    ORDER BY 
        datetime DESC
END
```

I am trying to call the stored procedure like so:

```
EXEC [dbo].[search_highlights] 1, 20, '"double play"'
```

When I run that, I get this error:

> Msg 7630, Level 15, State 2, Procedure dbo.search_highlights, Line 13 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Syntax error near '"' in the full-text search condition '"'.

When I try it without the `"`, the error goes away, but I get no results even though I should get them.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In SQL Server, you need to define a length for strings (the default in most contexts is a length of 1).

So, define the stored procedure as:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[search_highlights] (
    @page int = 1,
    @recsPerPage int = 20,
    @query VARCHAR(max) = ''
) AS . . .
```

Comment: Okay, I edited the sproc as you suggested. I still run into the same issues, though. I'll edit the post to reflect the (max) change.

Comment: I was able to figure out that "(max)" wasn't valid in this case. I had to use a number, then it worked.